# Emissivity of a perfect reflecting body

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

So from thermal classes, we kept saying reflectance + emissivity = 1, and thus for a perfect reflecting body, there's zero emissivity. But what about a reflecting body that is heated internally?

Say we have a perfectly polished chunk of material, that has electric heating wires embedded on the inside. As the body heats up, will it radiate anything at all? Or will the "perfect chunk of mirror" just heat up but will never glow no matter how hot it goes (until it melts?)

Perhaps there's some assumption in the relationship reflectance + emissivity = 1, that it is not true if there's heat transfer elsewhere? If the perfect reflecting body does glow and radiate heat, what would its emissivity be?

I have tried googling all over the place but can't find any relevant results, it kept giving me results about mirror reflecting lights but not the case when there's an internal heat source

Comment: Since we are talking about a body that has a close to 0 emissivity, we know that the only method through which this body heats up is by conduction (therefore, any transfer from the internal energy source to the white body won't be through radiation but conduction). Now again, this white body too should not be able to radiate the energy outwards but  it can still lose this heat energy through conduction. If in vacuum, it should not lose any energy.

Comment: I think that the reflectivity + emissivity = 1 thing is only true for opaque materials -- it must be something like reflectivity + emissivity + transmissivity, because I've seen warm silicon wafers in infrared (3-5 microns) and they look like they're at room temperature -- _and_ they look somewhat reflective and somewhat transmissive.

Answer (score 1):

Find a YouTube (or other) video of someone casting aluminum -- like [this one](https://youtu.be/HjJGjlpMfv0?t=249) at around 4:10 in.

The aluminum is molten and silvery; it looks like freshly shined aluminum at room temperature.  The inside of the crucible is red from heat.  The aluminum is red hot, too -- it's just that it has a reflectance of nearly 1 for visible light, and an emissivity of nearly zero, so that light doesn't get out.